# Android push notification issue

Tags: android, node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement push notification in my apps. 
I can get the notification in my device. But I get some error message.

> 02-23 15:33:31.904 17918-17918/com.radaee.reader E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement<>
>   02-23 15:33:31.904 17918-17918/com.radaee.reader E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
>   02-23 15:33:31.904 17918-22512/com.radaee.reader W/Bundle: Key google.sent_time expected String but value was a java.lang.Long.  The default value  was returned.      
>                                                              --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
>   02-23 15:33:31.914 17918-22512/com.radaee.reader W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
>                                                              java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>                                                                  at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1121)
>                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.gcm.zza.zzae(Unknown Source)
>                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
>                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzn(Unknown Source)
>                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzm(Unknown Source)
>                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   02-23 15:33:31.914 17918-22512/com.radaee.reader D/MyGcmListenerService: onMessageReceived
>   02-23 15:33:31.914 17918-22512/com.radaee.reader D/MyGcmListenerService: From: 631033776588
>   02-23 15:33:31.914 17918-22512/com.radaee.reader D/MyGcmListenerService: Message: Bundle[{google.sent_time=1487835190910, key1=testtesttest, key2=message2, type=notification, google.message_id=0:1487835190917734%768342b8768342b8, notification=Bundle[{body=432432, icon=ic_launcher, title=PDF Upload}], collapse_key=com.radaee.reader}]
>   02-23 15:33:31.914 17918-22512/com.radaee.reader D/MyGcmListenerService: type: notification
>   02-23 15:33:31.914 17918-22512/com.radaee.reader D/MyGcmListenerService: show notification

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.push.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission android:name="com.push.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="true"   android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.radaee.reader.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"    />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.radaee.reader" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.radaee.reader" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.radaee.reader.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.radaee.reader.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.radaee.reader.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
 </application><uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.push.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission android:name="com.push.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="true"   android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.radaee.reader.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"    />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.radaee.reader" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.radaee.reader" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.radaee.reader.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.radaee.reader.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.radaee.reader.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
 </application>
```

Thanks for help!!

Comment: post your manifest file code

Comment: you using FCM? So where is your MyFirebaseMessagingService & MyFirebaseInstanceIDService in manifest?

Comment: I don't use FCM. I use the gcm.

Answer (score 0):

**String and Long are completely different types you cannot cast them**
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to to java.lang.String

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But I don't know where can cast them

Comment: gcm library is the latest

Comment: Please refer this link 1.  https://github.com/morinel/gcmpush/issues/45 , 2. https://github.com/morinel/gcmpush/blob/master/src/nl/vanvianen/android/gcm/GCMIntentService.java#L108